# How to get string from API depending on another string in same section?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api

(Sorry if the title doesn't make much sense, I had no idea how to word the question right and that was the best way I could think of)

So I have an API (the steam API) that returns something like this:

```
   {
        "playerstats": {
            "steamID": "76561197962837077",
            "gameName": "ValveTestApp260",
                "stats": [
                    {
                        "name": "total_kills",
                        "value": 3255
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "total_deaths",
                        "value": 4816
                    },
                    ...
                    {
                        "name": "total_shots_hit",
                        "value": 3642
                    }
                    {
                        "name": "total_shots_fired",
                        "value": 4572
                    }
                    ...
                ],
        }
}
```

So I want to get the value for `total_shots_hit` and `total_shots_fired`, but it's in a different order for different people so I was wondering how I would get the value depending on the name in each of the sections? The way I'm doing it right now is by doing `statsResponse.playerstats.stats[39].value`, but it's not in the 39th spot for everyone, so I was wondering how I would get it? I'm using JavaScript/jQuery if that helps at all.

Any help is appreciated :)

EDIT: Figured out how to do it, I used a for loop to go through every response until it found the item I wanted, then used that number to find the same value

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to find an object in an array by one of its properties.

```
var o = stats.find(function(item) {
    return item.name === 'total_shots_hit';
}

console.log(o.value) // value property, e.g. 3642
```

Comment: Whenever I try that it gives me an error saying `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
    at XMLHttpRequest.statsRequest.onreadystatechange`, I tried converting it to an array since its Array.find(), but it just gives me an error with the `console.log(o.value)`, and if I do `console.log(o)` it just says `undefined`.

Comment: @ConnorS Perhaps it would help to see more of your code, since what I've provided certainly works in my testing. I don't know how XMLHttpRequest comes into the picture.